# Devise login dynamically, but reloads the page instead

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've created a widget that lets users install it with a line of JS script and it will prompt them to login, but it seems i have incorrectly setup the dynamic login for devise.

I basically need users to be able to login dynamically (can't reload pages because the widget is on a 3rd party site). And yes, i did make sure that the server which is hosting my widget is running at the same time.

How I'm rendering the login page: `<%=j (render 'devise/sessions/new') %>`

devise/sessions/_new.html.erb:

```
<h2>Log in</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), format: :json, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                <%= f.label :remember_me %>
        </div>
        <% end -%>
            <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
```

widget.js.erb:

```
//DEVISE CODE TO MAKE AJAX FUNCTIONAL
  var Authentication = {
    callbackSubmit: function(){
      var self = this;

      $("form").bind("ajax:success", function(e, response, status, xhr){
        if(response.success){
          window.location.reload();
        }else{
          self.errorsFromServer();
        }
      });
    },
  }

    Authentication.callbackSubmit();
});
```

My error: [image]

ROUTES:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions'}
```

Comment: Hey Raidspec -- could you show us your routes? You have a routing error. Do you have something like this? `devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register', edit: 'settings' }` in `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: This is my route right now: devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions'}. It shouldn't even be going to that route though. It should be logging the user in dynamically. If anyone has a repo of this already done, i would LOVE you forever.